# javascript TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHtml is not a function

Tags: javascript, typeerror, getelementsbytagname

I'm getting the following error for a simple function below:

```
TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHtml is not a function
```

I'm just trying to understand the usage of getElementsByTagName.

```
function myFunc(){
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHtml("hello my name is vaani");
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="myFunc();">
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
</body>
```

Can someone tell me on where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`innerHTML` but not `innerHtml`, and it is not a function, you should set the string to this property.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML = "hello my name is vaani";
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML="hello my name is vaani";
```